# Using Net Core HttpClient to call API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, mailgun, asp.net-core-3.1

Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and RestSharp I am calling Mailgun API to send an email with:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient ();
client.BaseUrl = new Uri ($"https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox{id}.mailgun.org");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator ("api", key);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "messages";
request.AddParameter ("from", "John <john@example.com>");
request.AddParameter ("to", "mary@example.com");
request.AddParameter ("subject", "Hello API RestSharp");
request.AddParameter ("text", "Testing Mailgun!");
request.Method = Method.POST;
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

This works fine. Then I tried the same with ASP.NET Core HttpClient:

```
try {

  using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox{id}.mailgun.org") }) {

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
        Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"api:{key}")));

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
      new KeyValuePair<String, String>("from", "John <john@example.com>"),
      new KeyValuePair<String, String>("to", "mary@example.com"),
      new KeyValuePair<String, String>("subject", "Hello API Net Core"),
      new KeyValuePair<String, String>("text", "Testing Mailgun!")
    });

    var result = await client.PostAsync("messages", content);

  }

} catch(Exception e) {

  var ex = e;

}
```

I get an OK response but the email is not sent and there is nothing on Mailgun Logs.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the value of result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result?

Comment: I tried result.StatusCode and get a 200 OK response. That is why I am having some difficulty determine what is wrong. But with RestSharp it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you can log the Exception in database or throw that you will be able to solve this problem

Comment: I placed the code inside a Try / Catch block and I do not have any exception.

Comment: can you refer this  https://github.com/emanuelpaul/asp-net-core-mailgun-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Is seems that when using Net Core Http Client the base address must be only:

```
 https://api.mailgun.net
```

And everything else must be in the resource, e.g:

```
v3/sandbox{id}.mailgun.org/messages
```